# Handle unknown characters

Tags: string, xslt, substring, keystroke

I'm in need to retrieve a substring from a text. The text is returned by a device and the problem is it sends it with unknown characters in it. What I'm trying to achieve is to retrieve the value '1' at the end but the XSLT statement would fail due to the JUNK characters(shown as **BS** and in a vi editor as **^H**).

Is there a way I can remove these keystroke characters out of the text and use regular string functions in XSLT?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you guys!

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before('show owp onu next-available port gpon_1/2$nu next-available port gpon_1/2           /          3         :        81.' , '.')"/>
```

Comment: The code section wouldn't show the unknown characters. They are actually BS keystroke characters.

Answer (score 0):

If your data contains a Backspace control character then it isn't legal XML, and if it isn't legal XML then you can't process it using XSLT. You have to deal with the problem at the stage when you are turning the text returned by the device into XML.